# Como criar um contador de cores? - Flutter

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, dart

Preciso criar um sistema de proporção que conte quantos marrons, quantos pretos e quantos brancos têm dentro do quadrado. Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nesse caso,** tem-se 9 marrons, 3 pretos e 4 brancos. Ou seja, uma proporção 9:3:4. Cada conjunto de letras representa um resultado (`result`) e este pode variar, consequentemente, as cores podem variar também. Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de adicionar um texto com algo do tipo (Proporção: 9:4:3) em cima do quadro da imagem.
Eu tentei criar uma variável para cada cor (exemplo: `countBlack`, `countWhite`...) mas tive dificuldade em acessá-las.

**Aqui está o código que é representado pela imagem:**

```
class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  Color checkdominantA(String predominantGamete, String resultado) {
    Color color = Colors.black;
    var countBrown = 0;
    var countYellow = 0;
    var countBlack = 0;
    var countWhite = 0;
    var countRed = 0;
    var proportion = '';


    if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
        resultado.contains('A') &&
        resultado.contains('P')) {
      countBrown += 1;
      return color = Colors.brown;
    } else if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
        resultado.contains('A') &&
        resultado.contains('pp')) {
      countBlack += 1;
      return color = Colors.black;
    } else if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
        resultado.contains('aa')) {
      countWhite += 1;
      return color = Colors.white;
    } else if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa') {
      proportion = 'Proporção: ${countBrown}, ${countBlack}, ${countWhite}'; //Tentei fazer assim
    }
return color
}
```

**E aqui está o código onde eu devo acessar a proporção:** (está na mesma classe que o código acima)

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        //title: é aqui que deve ter a proporção que varia de acordo com a quantidade de cada cor   Proporção: 9:4:3 <--(exemplo)
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: widget.result1 + '  ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: checkdominantA(widget.predominant, widget.result1),
                    height: 2.5,
                    letterSpacing: 0.7,
                  ),
                ),
              //...
                TextSpan(
                  text: widget.result16 + '  ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: checkdominantA(widget.predominant, widget.result16),
                    height: 2.5,
                    letterSpacing: 0.7,
                  ),
                ),
      ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Por favor, evite colocar imagens em posts. Para mais informações, você pode ler [este post sobre como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485).

Comment: Eu precisei colocar para deixar a pergunta mais fácil de entender. A imagem não se trata de linhas de código, é o próprio aplicativo em si.

Comment: Correto e meu argumento se mantém. Caso a imagem se torne indisponível futuramente, ficará mais difícil de entender sua pergunta. O ideal é evitar o envio de imagens por conta desse tipo de possibilidade.

Comment: Onde você guarda a informação das strings que vão ser exibidas na tela? Essa função ```checkdominantA``` é chamada em que momento? Pelo que entendi ela parece ser chamada apenas uma vez, certo? Significa que ela vai ser chamada com uma string gigante que contém todas essas sub-strings? Poderia dar um exemplo de chamada dessa função? (O que que você passaria em resultado e em predominantGamete)

Comment: Acabei de editar o segundo código. A função `checkDominantA` é chamada cada vez que cada result (1 até o 16) for chamado. Ela serve para alterar a cor de cada resultado baseado em qual letra é 'dominante'.

Comment: As strings que vão aparecer na tela variam de acordo com o que o usuário inseriu nos dois TextsFields que têm na tela inicial. É como se fosse duas strings 'pais' que dão origem a 16 strings 'filhas', essas strings filhas são os resultados que variam de acordo com o que foi inserido nos dois pais

Comment: Entendi! Então, o problema de fazer dentro de uma função que é chamada muitas vezes é que ela está dentro do Build() e seria chamada para qualquer re-construção de tela. Idealmente você poderia fazer uma outra função ```checkProportion``` que é chamada apenas uma vez para todas as 16 strings. (Colocando no ```initState()``` por exemplo). Assim a função de cor fica responsável apenas pela cor de uma sub-string, e a função de proporção recebe todas as strings e retorna a proporção. Existe algum motivo especial para você ter feito 16 variaveis e não uma lista de strings?

Comment: Na verdade não tem nenhum motivo especial para eu ter feito dessa forma, uma pessoa aqui no fórum também havia falado para eu fazer uma lista de strings mas senti dificuldade pois sou iniciante e aí preferi não arriscar. O lado ruim é que o código fica muito grande, admito.

Comment: Você poderia me ajudar a criar essa função `checkProportion` que você mencionou? Estou travado em como montar a estrutura inicial dela

Comment: Escrever ela sem usar uma lista fica enorme. Com uma lista você poderia percorrer os 16 elementos e fazer a mesma coisa em todos sem problemas. Mas ao fazer 16 variáveis, você precisa escrever o mesmo código 16 vezes. (Também facilitaria ali nos seus TextSpans, você fez 16 iguais.) Ficaria algo bem parecido com o que você já escreveu. Um contador pra cada cor, e para cada variável você incrementa o contador respectivo. No final você teria a proporção. O problema com o que você já fez é que aquela função é chamada para apenas uma sub-string e aí não tem como ela ter informação de todas.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130263/discussion-between-bilbo-bo-and-naslausky).